# Strange Oracle DB baheviour

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join

I have an Oracle Schema with two tables: `people` and `people_profile`.

I have one row in `people` with `uid = '12345678X'`, and another row in `people_profile` with `uid = '12345678X'` and `profile = 'admin'`

Why the next query...

```
select * from people 
   inner join people_profile 
   on people_profile.uid = people.uid 
where people.uid = '12345678X' and people_profile.profile = 'admin'
```

... does not return any row??

Is just a matter of concept or is it something I am missing?
I am not a newbie with SQL, but I am completely stuck in this, although I will probably be something trivial...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you 100% sure the `uid` values are exactly as you show them? You may have errant spaces that are not visible. That's the first thing I would look for.

Comment: @andcl - [Demo](http://rextester.com/JDX36799) for you.

Comment: We get a lot of questions here along the lines of "Strange Oracle DB baheviour". Most of the time it turns out the data in the tables was different from what the Seeker thought it was. I'm not saying Oracle's bug-free, but that's the way to bet.

Answer (score 0):

check character by character the values in the columns.  this is a data issue.